# How to Set Loader When a Component API call occurs or State Value change

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I created a react App which contains a lot of components and each component has a specific store, but that store I call in global store. Now the issue is that I want to show loader whenever there are something in pending state like API call occurred or state value changed then show me loader on the whole screen, but I want it when I click a button or something else and in this time if it take time then show me loader.

Secondly I have try with API call manually like before API call become true and after that it will become false, but I have a lot of API calls. I don't want like this I want to have some generic function which is called automatically when API call or something else occurs.

[image: axios code]

I use an axios interceptor in which every API call goes there interceptor but I can not set loader there.

[image: thunks]

[image: state slice]

I have try manually but I want it to become globally and do not set to true false on every call or anything else

Comment: Please [edit] the post to include actual formatted and readable snippets of code instead of images of text. Images are less accessible, can be more difficult to read, and are not copy/pasteable in terms of reproducing issues. See [mcve]. Can you also clarify what "loader" is that you refer to? The post/issue/question is unclear. What exactly do you need help with or answered?

Comment: @DrewReese i want to make a generic loader which call when app is not ready let suppose when i fetch data it take some time at that time i want to show loader. but i set at manually but i have a lot of api call so i do not want to do it manually

Comment: Do *what* manually? It's unclear what you are trying to accomplish or what any issue is that you might be facing.

Comment: @DrewReese i mean that when i call API before the API call i set a state Loader to True and when Response come then i write again state to false the loader so a want that i do not write loader to true and then false i  want a function which is generic can control whole App which automatically find that API call is occurred and that time show loader

Comment: @DrewReese Thank you sir for your such a valuable answer sir is there any other solution like to use HOC or Window some function that automatically fine that something is an pending state. sir i have child store for every folder and that child folder have one parent store so sir if you help me about this issue i will be very thankful of you

Comment: @DrewReese sir i mean that we have a global loader that is call automatically when there is something loading like API call occur or MAP function or set State value etc.

Comment: The matcher solution I provided below ***is*** the Higher Order Function way to do what you ask, but if you don't about any specific set of actions and only want to know when ***any*** thunk is pending or fulfilled/rejected you can use the `isPending`/`isFulfilled`/`isRejected` HOFs directly, e.g. `builder.addMatcher(isPending, () => { loading: true })`. Keep in mind this might not actually be the logic you want as ***any*** thunk ***anywhere*** can be dispatched at ***any*** time, and settle at ***any*** time. I see this leading to very sporadic loading indicators.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reducer case functions ***are*** the functions that "see" that Thunks have been dispatched. If handling each thunk individually is too much then you could use a [matching utility](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/matching-utilities) to handle multiple actions with a single reducer case function. Use a single `employee.loading` state.

Example:

```
import {
  createSlice,
  createAsyncThunk,
  isPending,
  isFulfilled,
  isRejected,
} from '@reduxjs/toolkit';

const initialState = {
  loading: false,
  data: [],
};

... createAsyncThunks ...

export const employeeSlice = createSlice({
  name: "employee",
  initialState,
  extraReducers: builder => {
    builder
      .addMatcher(
        isPending(saveEmployeeData, editEmployeeData, getallEmployeeData),
        (state) => {
          state.loading = true;
        }
      )
      .addMatcher(
        isFulfilled(saveEmployeeData, editEmployeeData, getallEmployeeData),
        (state, action) => {
          state.loading = false;
          state.data = action.payload 
        }
      )
      .addMatcher(
        isRejected(saveEmployeeData, editEmployeeData, getallEmployeeData),
        (state, action) => {
          state.loading = false;
          // set any error state ???
        }
      )
  },
});
```